# Flutter: How to auto run socket io client in forenground mobile app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to run socket io client autoRunOnBoot and forenground in flutter.
I have searched and read some packages related to backgound services, but mostly for notifications.
I am still confused about the implementation for socket, anyone help me

```
socket = IO.io(
      'http://$ip',
      IO.OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['websocket'])
          .disableAutoConnect()
          // .setExtraHeaders({'foo': 'bar'})
          .setQuery({
            'userID': userID.toString(),
            'token': token.toString(),
            'id' : "${androidInfo.fingerprint}${androidInfo.id}"
          })
          .build(),
    );
```

If you want to call the socket, I just call it like this because this socket is inside the GetxController class

```
final sock = Get.put(SocketController());
await sock.socketInit();
```